# writing xlsx file from csv in python

Tags: python, xlsx

This is my code which loads the spreadsheet from doc excel file and creates a csvTranslations.csv, translations.py and translations.xlsx. The problem is it is creating a blank translattions.xlsx file and I don't know what am i doing wrong.

```
import os
import random
import re
import csv
import requests
import io
import sys
import copy
import xlrd
import codecs
import time
import xlrd
from collections import OrderedDict
import simplejson as json
import xlsxwriter
from pandas.io.excel import ExcelWriter
import pandas
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils  import get_column_letter
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
```

> the function which will be called

```
def gen_translations():
    try:
        import xlrd
    except:
        print "Missing xlrd module!"
        return
    #return
    csv_file = 'translations.xlsx'
    if not os.path.exists(csv_file):
        print "Unable to update translations due to missing csv file!"
        return

    print "updating translations..."
    o = open("translations.py", "wb")
```

> link to the google doc

```
url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g3nk_yzQxQFSxPN2lCvWwiHH8MgAqhpu5S763FRD_5I/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=translations"
    r = requests.get(url, verify=False)

    ow = io.open("csvTranslations.csv", "wb")

    ow.write(r.content)

    ow.close()



    try:
        print >> o, header
    except:
        print >> o, "#CANNOT PRINT HEADER:%s" % repr(header)

    with open("csvTranslations.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
        docreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        headers = next(docreader)
        for row in docreader:
            decoded_row = [entry.decode("utf8") for entry in row]
            decoded_row[6] = translate(decoded_row[2], to_X)

            try:
                id = int(decoded_row[0])
            except:
                break
            keyword = decoded_row[1]
            languages = decoded_row[2:]
            '''
            try:
                print u" ; ".join(languages)
            except:
                print "#CANNOT PRINT:%s"%repr(languages)
            '''
            try:
                print >> o, "    %s = Word(%d, %s)" % (keyword, id, languages)
            except:
                print >> "ERROR: CANNOT PRINT %s = Word(%d,%s)" % (repr(keyword), id, repr(languages))
        try:
            print >> o, footer
        except:
            print >> o, "#ERROR CANNOT PRINT FOOTER:%s" % repr(footer)
        o.close()
        print "done!"
```

> it seems that the problem is here because both csvTranslations and translations.py are being written but the translations.xlsx is not

```
        csv.register_dialect('colons', delimiter=',')

        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='colons')

        wb = Workbook()
        dest_filename = r"translations.xlsx"

        ws = wb.worksheets[0]

        for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):
            for column_index, cell in enumerate(row):
                column_letter = get_column_letter((column_index + 1))
                ws['%s%s'%(column_letter, (row_index + 1))].value = cell

        wb.save(filename=dest_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to read "csvTranslations.csv" through twice, but you only open the file once.  So, once your script has finished reading in order to write to translations.py, the *file pointer* to csvTranslations.csv is now located at the end of the file, and further attempts to read from csvfile return no data (instead, they indicate "you're already at the end of the file!", causing your loop at `for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):` to exit.)  The easiest way to fix the problem would be to open csvTranslations.csv a second time, prior to the line `reader = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='colons')`; this gives you a new pointer into the file, this one back at the beginning.